# Search Results not visible

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-data, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a table view with a search display controller.  When I type a search the log shows me the search is working and filtering properly however the screen only shows "No Results".  I'm using Core Data if that makes a difference.

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    return [searchResults count];
}
else{
    return[[self.fetchedResultsController sections]count];
}
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {

id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> secInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];\
return [secInfo numberOfObjects];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell;
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

if (tableView != self.tableView) {
    NSLog(@"Found searchDisplayController");
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
} else {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"Found regular table View");
}

    // Configure the cell...
    Instance *instance = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
    cell.textLabel.text = instance.name;
    }
```

Here are NumberOfRowsInSection and Number:

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
     if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    return [searchResults count];
}
     else{
    return[[self.fetchedResultsController sections]count];
}
}
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
     id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> secInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];\
     return [secInfo numberOfObjects];
 }
```

Comment: where are you updating the contents of the cell ?

Comment: Just below:    Instance *instance = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    //more search data
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = instance.name;
    }

Comment: @Isaac: Can you add that code to your question? That makes it easier to read. - The `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` methods would also be helpful.

Comment: Have you looked at the logic that presents the "No results" message and worked back from there to see why it thinks there are no results?

Comment: (Formatting would be nice.)

Answer (score 0):

Check your implementation of `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection`.
In the first, you should return 1 if it's the search table view (1 section).
In `numberOfRowsInSection` you should also check the given tableView argument as you did in `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and return `[searchResults count]`.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your implementation be something like :-

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
     if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) 
     {
       return 1;
     }
     else
     {
       return[[self.fetchedResultsController sections]count];
     }
}
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
    if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
      return [searchResults count];
    }
     id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> secInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];\
     return [secInfo numberOfObjects];
 }
```

If the number of search results is high, then I would suggest using another Fetched Results Controller instead of an array.

Comment: thanks for this. I implemented it and inserted log statements to see how the code functioned.  Everything was seen and in the log I can see that search is accurately filtering my search but the display still shows No Results.  Any other places I should look?

Comment: If you are seeing a physical message "No Results", then is there any code which outputs this message ?

Comment: I don't think so. Under CellForRowAtIndexPath I defined what should populate a cell if the tableView == self.searchResultsController.searchResultsTableView.  Shouldn't that configure the search result cells?